# Spread the list of multiple dictionaries into multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where one column looks like this:

```
df['handling_unit'] = [{'id': 87, 'handling_unit': 'tyu', 'quantity'...
1                                                    []
2                                                    []
3     [{'id': 88, 'handling_unit': 'tyu', 'quantity'...
4     [{'id': 141, 'handling_unit': 'kakjfkls', 'qua...
5     [{'id': 146, 'handling_unit': 'tyu', 'quantity...
6     [{'id': 148, 'handling_unit': 'ff', 'quantity'...
7     [{'id': 155, 'handling_unit': 'kakjfkls', 'qua...
8     [{'id': 156, 'handling_unit': 'hellow', 'quant...
9     [{'id': 159, 'handling_unit': 'time pass', 'qu...
10    [{'id': 162, 'handling_unit': 'tyu', 'quantity...
11    [{'id': 195, 'handling_unit': 'undefined', 'qu...
12                                                   []
```

There can be multiple dictionaries in the list and they can also be empty.
how do I expand all of them into multiple columns such as 'handling_unit1', handling_unit1_quantity, handling_unit2, handling_unit2_quantity....?

Comment: Without seeing actual data, it's hard to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

you might be able to use `pandas.json_normalize()` to flatten your nested data

Comment: I tried this "df = pd.json_normalize(data, sep='_')" but it's of no use

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.